# React render not changing when calling from Button

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hooks

When I click the login or register button in the following react code, the renderView() function is not rendering the Login(or the Register) component on the page.
When I log the value of e.currentTarget.value in the console, the correct values are getting logged when the button is clicked.
How do I fix this?
I want the corresponding components to be displayed when I click the Login or Register Buttons

```
const AppHomePage = () => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [renderVal, setRenderVal] = useState(0);

    const renderView = () => {
        switch(renderVal){
            case 0:
                return <Page />
            case 1:
                return <Register />
            case 2:
                return <Login />
            default:
                return <Page />
        }
    }

    const ButtonChange = (e) => {
        setRenderVal(e.currentTarget.value);
    }

    return(
        <div>
            <AppBar className={classes.root} position='static' >
                <Toolbar className={classes.appbar}>
                    <Button className={classes.buttons} value={1} variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={ButtonChange}>
                        Register
                    </Button>
                    <Button className={classes.buttons} value={2} variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={ButtonChange}>
                        Login
                    </Button>
                </Toolbar>
            </AppBar>
            <div>
                { renderView() }
            </div>
            <CssBaseline />
        </div>
    )
}
const Login = () => {
    return(
        <div>
            <p>login</p>
        </div>
    )
}

const Register = () => {
    return(
        <div>
           register
        </div>
    )
}
const Page = () => {
    return(
        <div>
            page
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Could you add in ButtonChange a simple this.setState({}); and see what happen?

Answer (score 1):

Pass the value inside onClick function. Use an arrow function and pass the id like 1 or 2. `onClick={() => ButtonChange(1)}`

```
<Button className={classes.buttons} variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={() => ButtonChange(1)}>
                        Register
                    </Button>


<Button className={classes.buttons} variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={()=>ButtonChange(2)}>
                        Login
                    </Button>
```

Now in ButtonChange function get the value passed in previous step.

```
const ButtonChange = (id) => {
        setRenderVal(id);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by simply changing the cases from case 1: to case '1': and so on...